# Return not exists record in the table

Tags: mysql

How to get the IDs which doesn't have any record in the table? Like for example,

```
select id,name,mail from users where id in(2,3,4,5,6)
```

The query returns output for the record 2,3,4 but not 5 and 6 as there is no record exists in the table.

Now i want to know what are the ids that doesn't have record in the table. Is there any way to get this output in mysql?

Comment: If you more than one table to refer,It is possible.

Comment: The issue is that you are trying to return data... that doesn't exist :) If that data exists in your application then you will have to post process the query in your application.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT id
FROM (
  SELECT 2 as id
  union 
  SELECT 3
  union 
  SELECT 4
  union 
  SELECT 5
  union 
  SELECT 6
) q
WHERE q.id NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM users )
```

Comment: This is ok for having static ids and i gave that as an example for better understanding. But all the ids come as dynamic here....sorry if i am not clear in explaining...

Comment: To select and display "rows" in MySql, they must be retrieved from a table, a resultset of the query, or a view. You can create a temporary table and save these items in this table. You can create a dynamic SQL (with UNIONs). If you want to pass these values as a string, you must create a procedure that parses this string into individual values and saves them into a table. Unfortunately, MySql is awkward, it's not so easy to perform such a task in MySql, other databases are much more user friendly, take a look how easy it is in PostgreSQL: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f3e48/8